How can I reduce power consumption of realtek ethernet device?
I have a laptop with debian 12 and the Realtek Ethernet Controller consumes around 10W according to powertop:
Power est.              Usage       Events/s    Category       Description
  11.9 W      0.0 pkts/s                Device         Network interface: enp4s0 (r8168)
 92.7 mW     97.5 ms/s     191.0        Process        [PID 35665] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt3 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -background none -noreset -ke
 84.2 mW     88.6 ms/s      15.4        Process        [PID 36881] /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server

The power consumption happens even though the device is down:
$ ip a
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:3e:43:5d:a5:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Is there any way I can disable, this device completely or at least reduce the power consumption?

Some additional diagnostics:
$ lspci | grep -i "Ethernet"
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

$ nmcli device show enp4s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         A8:3E:43:5D:A5:1A
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --


Don't trust powertop; that's all. I don't know why, but the number it estimates is clearly wrong.

They are not always right yet it's still quite useful to bring power consumption down. And in many cases they are correct.

yes, but here they are definitely none of these :)
